# How rename property while serializing/deserializing using Jackson without annotations?

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, jackson

How to make Jackson rename field `id` to `_id` while serializing and vice-versa while deserializing, **without adding any annotation** on the class?

For example this object:

```
{
  "id": "abc",
  "value": "foo"
}
```

should be serialized to:

```
{
  "_id": "abc",
  "value": "foo"
}
```

I want it to work for any class, without the need of annotating each `id` field with `@JsonProperty("_id")`

Comment: The way to go is Jackson mixins (e.g. see [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue)). You **still have to add annotations**, but **in a different class** (the mixin).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a rather nice solution to this problem.

```kotlin
val document = objectMapper.convertValue(data, Document::class.java)
if ("id" in document) {
    document["_id"] = document["id"]
    document.remove("id")
}
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(document)
```

First convert this object to map/tree-like structure (like Document if you're working with Mongo), which is easy to edit, and after making your changes serialize/deserialize it to your desired format. I'm not sure about a performance of this solution, but it seems to be very straight-forward.